# How to make crawling and extracting data in each pager links?

Tags: php, dom, curl, web-crawler, domcrawler

I want to extract all the attributes `name=""` of a website,

example html

```
<div class="link_row">
    <a href="" class="listing_container" name="7777">link</a>
</div>
```

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.onedomain.com/plus?ca=11_c&o=1');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='link_row']/a[@class='listing_container']/@name" );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
    echo $n->nodeValue."\n<br>";
}
?>
```

Result is:

```
7777
```

### This code is working fine, but need not be limited to one pager number.

`http://www.onedomain.com/plus?ca=11_c&o=1`  pager attr is `"o=1"`

I would like once you finish with `o=1`, follow with `o=2` 
to my variable defined `$last=556` is equal `http://www.onedomain.com/plus?ca=11_c&o=556`

Could you help me?
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for (or while) loop. I don't see `$last` in your provided code so I've statically set the max value plus one.

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
for($i =1; $i < 557; $i++) {
    @$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.onedomain.com/plus?ca=11_c&o=' . $i);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
    $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='link_row']/a[@class='listing_container']/@name" );
    foreach ($nodelist as $n){
        echo $n->nodeValue."\n<br>";
    }
}
```

Simpler example:

```
for($i =1; $i < 557; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: And I can do to wait five seconds between each item?

Comment: I'm not sure at what point you want to delay the execution; the `sleep` function should be able to handle that, http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php. Something like `sleep(5);`.